# display of different screen using NavigationContainer not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

if My functions homescreen and settingsscreen inside App.js working to display the screen and If I do separate screens as different .js  not working when I click on the tabs

App.js

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeSreen';
import SettingsScreen from './screens/SettingsScreen';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

HomeScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';


function HomeScreen() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

SettingsScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';





  function SettingsScreen() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Settings!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried this `export default function HomeScreen()`

Comment: ya its working .... I missed that export default thanks